# PostgreSQL query, LIKE operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

The documentation tells me `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` are used in SQL to search if cells contain/starts/ends with certain characters.

I'm trying to use this in PostgreSQL which tells me the operator does not exist. My query:

```
SELECT * FROM "City"."models" 
WHERE (("City"."models".identifier NOT LIKE'%$%') 
AND
     (("City"."models".id LIKE '%2%') 
     OR 
     ("City"."models".id LIKE '%1%'))) 

ORDER BY "City"."models".town_id ASC LIMIT 10
```

Column types:

```
identifier->uuid
id->int
town_id->int
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Show us some sample data, preferably in a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and also post your query there

Comment: you should really post the complete error message.

Comment: My guess is "identifier" and "id" are not strings. LIKE won't work with numeric values.

Comment: `LIKE` is not applicable to integers, you'll have to use something like `CAST(id as VARCHAR) LIKE '%2%'` etc. But that looks weird in general, why do you want to filter integers like text?

Comment: it looks weird and i'm sure the error message tells him exactly that int does not work with `LIKE`

Comment: Part of the error message will be "ERROR: operator does not exist: integer !~~ unknown"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM "City"."models" 
WHERE (("City"."models".identifier::varchar NOT LIKE'%$%') 
AND
     (("City"."models".id::varchar LIKE '%2%') 
     OR 
     ("City"."models".id::varchar LIKE '%1%'))) 

ORDER BY "City"."models".town_id ASC LIMIT 10
```